# How do i make a python variable with infinite digits behind comma

Tags: python

Im working with a math paradox in python and i need the number variable to be 100% accurate, i want the variable/number to not have a limit to how many digits it is behind the comma. Im sorry if my english is bad and thanks for all help :D.

```
    addition = 0.5
    time = 0
    lengthWalked = 0
    nr = 0
    while True:
        nr += 1
        time += addition
        lengthWalked += addition
        addition = addition / 2
        print("nr: ",nr,"time: ",time,"Length walked: ",lengthWalked)
```

What this code does is add 0,5 then half of that or 0,25 then 0,125. You get the point. If the variable could hold infinite numbers it would continue forever with adding half the amount and never reach 1 but it only adds numbers 53 times and reaches 1 at 54

if your wondering, yes this is based on Zeno´s paradox

Comment: And your question is??

Comment: you will need inf digits to hold such a number. So because you can have at most float 128 the smallest difference can only be 2**-128

Comment: This would have to be done symbolically, not numerically. If done numerically you'll eventually run out of memory, then storage, then atoms in the universe.

Comment: You can have *arbitrary* precision with `decimal`, but you cannot have "infinite" precision because there isn't infinite computing resources (in this case, memory). Remember, computers are fundamentally machines, not magic.

Comment: In the world of computers ***infinite floats*** make no sense. If a number has unlimited digits and decimals, the computer will continuously generate it, until it eventually burns the processor...

Comment: Yes, i agree. But is there any way i can make a variable where my memory is the limit. I think i have enough memory for my task anyways, if not i can simply dedicate some harddisk or ssd space to virtual ram.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Thank juanpa, this answers my question.

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder what do you mean?

Answer (score 5):

No physical computer can hold infinite data, but you can get high precision to the limits of process memory by using the `fractions` module:

```
>>> from fractions import Fraction
>>> walked = Fraction(0)
>>> addition = Fraction(1,2)
>>> while True:
...     walked += addition
...     print(walked)
...     addition /= 2
...
1/2
3/4
7/8
15/16
31/32
63/64
127/128
255/256
511/512
1023/1024
2047/2048
4095/4096
8191/8192
#snip...
35835915874844867368926665039455365204129607103827921929128897517135717358887465018319582487209796698111/35835915874844867368919076489095108449946327955754392558399825615420669938882575126094039892345713852416
71671831749689734737853330078910730408259214207655843858257795034271434717774930036639164974419593396223/71671831749689734737838152978190216899892655911508785116799651230841339877765150252188079784691427704832
143343663499379469475706660157821460816518428415311687716515590068542869435549860073278329948839186792447/143343663499379469475676305956380433799785311823017570233599302461682679755530300504376159569382855409664
```

Answer (score 0):

[`sympy`](http://www.sympy.org/en/index.html) will solve your problem, and then some :

```
>>> from sympy import symbols, summation, oo
>>> i, n = symbols('i n', integer=True)
>>> f = lambda n: summation(1/2**i, (i, 1, n))
>>> f(n)
-2*2**(-n - 1) + 1
>>> 1 - f(n)
2*2**(-n - 1)
>>> f(n) < 1
True
>>> f(1000)
10715086071862673209484250490600018105614048117055336074437503883703510511249361224931983788156958581275946729175531468251871452856923140435984577574698574803934567774824230985421074605062371141877954182153046474983581941267398767559165543946077062914571196477686542167660429831652624386837205668069375/10715086071862673209484250490600018105614048117055336074437503883703510511249361224931983788156958581275946729175531468251871452856923140435984577574698574803934567774824230985421074605062371141877954182153046474983581941267398767559165543946077062914571196477686542167660429831652624386837205668069376
>>> f(oo)
1
```

So yes, `f(n)` :

- is stricly less than 1 for any `n`
- can be calculated by sympy with 100% accuracy for any `n`
- admits 1 as limit for `n->∞`